# Parse: Query local database is 20 times slower then sqlite

Tags: objective-c, parse-platform

I have a sqlite database with about 900 rows. 
To retrive an object with sqlite is extremely fast (about 5 ms):

```
"SELECT * FROM questions where questionId = 1;
```

I tried to implement Parse local datastore and query the database from it:

```
PFQuery *questionQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Questions"];
[questionQuery fromLocalDatastore];
[questionQuery fromPinWithName:@"Questions"];
[questionQuery whereKey:@"questionId" equalTo:@(1)];

// Get object
PFObject *object = [questionQuery getFirstObject];
```

This takes about 110 ms, or about 20 times longer then the sqlite.

Am I doing something wrong or is Parse just extremely slow?

Comment: I find Parse to be extremely slow sometimes. Seems they have peak busier times...

Comment: Please observe that this is from the local database, and no network.

Comment: If you want a specific solution you need to implement yourself. I haven't seen it documented but the old Parse cache was saved JSON files so don't make any assumptions about the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

try to use

> – getFirstObjectInBackground

ref: https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFQuery.html#//api/name/getFirstObjectInBackground